# Scroll reverts to top or bottom of page after click

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, scrolling

I'm having trouble with the scroll position on a website resetting after a click. If I scroll down (using a touchpad) on a webpage in Chrome to the middle of a page then middle click to open a link in a new tab, when I start to scroll again, it immediately sends me back to the top of the page. It does not scroll from the current position on the page, instead it goes back to the top.

Any idea why this is? I'm using 16.04.

Comment: I've been seeing this same issue on Linux Mint with Chrome 51. Driving me up the wall!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like unfortunately this is a bug in Chrome:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617834
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609748

Not sure if there's much to be done until they release a fix.